# How to register a modal window on ng-repeat object

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using jQuery to register modal window event on DOM element. The problem is jQuery only traverses once, so all DOM elements added by Angular ng-repeat directive are not registered. So I can't open the modal window..

I'm very new to AngularJS. Is there anyway I can refresh jQuery from within angularJS? Or do I have to write my own custom directive (it sounds really hard)? Or is there a proper way to accomplish this kind of task?

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('something').directive('popup', function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function () {
                   // tie up the modal events here 
                   $(".modal").modal('show');
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

in the ng-repeat just add the directive. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Sorry I know javascript but not that well..so this question might be idiotic: when you call $().modal, is this a function? Is it registered outside of AngularJS? If outside of AngularJS, where and how could you call it inside angular?

Comment: The problem was not with registering or anything like that. The problem is that angular renders the dom. We need to attach the events after they are loaded. The directives provide such flexibility. This is what I have done. forget the modal call it is just written to specify where the binding has to be done

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be wrapped in a directive. But you don't have to create the directive yourself because [someone else already did](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Comment: yeah...I unfortunately primarily use a jQuery-like library called Zepto.js and I also use Zurb Foundation 4. I'll have to do some (if not a lot of) modifications to AngularUI in order to just use it, but I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: OK. I found this paragraph on their github page: "you can customize directive's markup at will. One could even imagine providing a non-Boostrap version of the templates!" (: Thanks for the help